# spring-boot test externalisation

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

i have to to externalize the configuration to an independant module maven, and i will extend my classes test to get the configuration.
for example :
Module Webservices:

```
 public class ServiceTestConfiguration extends SpringBootTestConfiguration{
 }

 Module Tests:
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 public class SpringBootTestConfiguration { 
 }
```

is it possible to create the configuration classes in the module test and use it in the module webservices ?

i tried to do it like the example but i had a

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/module/test/SpringBootTestConfiguration
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
```

Comment: what is the question here?  Take some time to formulate the question properly. How can you expect someone to take their time to answer, if you don't have time to formulate the question...

Comment: did you inject your dependency in pom?

Comment: yes, i inject the dependency in the pom of the module webservices